# How to open a specific ViewController using QuickActions in iOS app created with Xcode and Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, quickaction

I created an iOS app with Xcode and Swift. That app contains five `UIViewControllers`. All `ViewControllers` are managed by a single `UITabBarController`.

I already configured some (static) QuickActions in Info.plist file.

I have problems with making them able to open a specific ViewController. Of cause, I already googled, but nothing worked for me. (Maybe because most people use `NavigationController`, but I cannot/don't want to use it.)

I uploaded my project here: http://www.filedropper.com/myapp. You can download it to picture my layout. There's also already some code to handle QuickActions in AppDelegate.swift. But unfortunately this code doesn't work. Maybe anybody can figure out the problem?

What code do I need to handle it?

Can anybody provide it please? Or does anybody know a simple manual/tutorial?

Regards, David.

P.S.: I tried this code, but it seems to work only with NavigationController?! Code:

Comment: do you want to swipe left or right to get the appropirate view  ? like youtube application.

Comment: No, I don't want to have it like this.

Comment: create custom class for tabbar controller . in that  you can set which view need to be shown on launch.